# libpng warning in python opencv2

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.0, libpng

I managed to install and successfully import cv2 on a linux(Debian) virtual machine, using python 2.7. I tried to take a picture using my webcam with the following piece of code:

```
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
tar_file = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + '.png'
camera_port = 0
ramp_frames = 30
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
def get_image():
    retval, im = camera.read()
    return im
for i in xrange(ramp_frames):
    temp = get_image()
camera_capture = get_image()
cv2.imwrite(tar_file, camera_capture)
camera = None
```

I have tested the code earlier on my windows 10 host machine and it works fine. When using this code the program successfully saves the file, but the file cannot be opened and the following error is displayed in the terminal:

```
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
```

The error occurs as the camera_capture object is a NoneType, why is this so?
How can I prevent this error from happening and successfully take a snapshot through my webcam?

Edit : The error appears the occur when the line "cv2.imwrite(tar_file, camera_capture)" is run. Upon further inspection the camera_capture variable is a NoneType and the retval value is False which would explain the width and height being 0. Why is the variable a NoneType and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Check your image before you write it into the file. And your code is ugly organized.

Comment: its roughly written just to demonstrate the error, the image variable I tried to write into the file is None.

Comment: You are NOT checking retval anywhere... are you sure, it is actually acquiring an image? The error basically tells you that you are saving an empty image. The NoneType it is returned if no image could be read from the camera.... You have to make sure the camera is connected, and check if retval is actually true

Comment: I assume the reason the error is happening would be an incorrect webcam configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is failing due to no data being written to the file. This causes the file to be empty and thus it cannot be opened. The reason the data returned is empty is most likely due to an incorrectly configured webcam. The solution to this is to connect the VM to the camera. If it still fails, try to install a driver on the VM for the webcam.